# Can I generate gcloud statements from existing AI Platform Notebook?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have created a Notebook instance from the GCP AI Platfrom Notebook GUI. Is there a way to generate the gcloud statement that will do this for future similar creations? I know I can create similar from the GUI, but I want to delete and re-create later.

Comment: I think you cannot but it's an excellent question and you should file a feature request on Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Thanks Daz, will do.

Comment: Issue here for voting: https://issuetracker.google.com/153682332.